# The length of an arc within two intersecting circles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

I found this mathematical expression for the length of a arc $l(r)$ i.e the shorter arc ACB. In other words, why is $l(r)$ equal to that expression with respect to R i.e $l (r) = 2r \arccos (r/2R)$? I have tried hard to prove it but I couldn't. I hope someone could give the clue to the answer. The diagram and question can be found the the attached picture

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Do you really mean $l(r)$ to be the length of the (shorter) arc from A to B along the inside circle of radius $r$? [You refer to the length of a chord in the question, which has another definition.]

Comment: @coffeemath! Yes the length of the shorter arc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$
l(r) = 2r \angle ADC.
$$

So we just need to compute $\angle ADC$. Let $Q$ be the center of the circle on the left. Note that $AD=r$ and $DQ=AQ=R$. It follows that $\angle ADQ=\angle ADC=\arccos(r/2R)$. To see why, note that $\triangle ADQ$ is isosceles and drop a perpendicular from $Q$ to the midpoint of $AD$.

Is that clear?

Comment: Thanks! Yes its clear!