# Probability density function for the radius half the length of two equal intersecting circles

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Considering [this diagram](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392822/the-length-of-an-arc-within-two-intersecting-circles), assuming a uniform distribution in the area of  UQWD, it is still not clear how the probability density function of r becomes $l(r)/S$. Where S is the area of UQWD. What is the proof for the pdf in this case? A schematic diagram is attached below for clarity.[image]

NB: I have taken time to go through [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) but I haven't gotten a strong clue yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parametrize the area UQWD in polar coordinate as
$$
{\cal A} = \{(r, \theta)| r\in [0, r_m], \theta\in [\pi-l(r)/(2 r), \pi+l(r)/(2 r)]\}
$$
For a given $r_0\in [0, r_m]$, one has

$$
P(r\le r_0) = \frac{1}{S}\int_0^{r_0} dr\int_{\pi-l(r)/(2r)}^{\pi+l(r)/(2r)} r d\theta = \frac{1}{S}\int_0^{r_0} l(r) d r
$$

Hence the density $\frac{l(r)}{S}\chi_{[0, r_m]}$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please could you simplify this a bit?

Comment: It can hardly be made simpler. I'm only using that the area in polar coordinates is given by $\int\int r dr d\theta$.

Comment: What does $\chi_{[0, r_m]}$ mean?  I am aware that $\int_0^{r_0} dr$ gives $r_0$

Comment: It is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of the interval $[0, r_m]$