# Intuition for Parametrization of an intersection of two circles

Tags: polar-coordinates, parametric

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517888/probability-density-function-for-the-radius-half-the-length-of-two-equal-interse?noredirect=1&lq=1), the parametrization of two circles was given based on their intersection. The idea seems simple and quite correct and intuitive. However, I don't understand the intuition behind the prametrization here i.e for the area UQWD. Specifically, extending the polar coordinates to $\pi- l(r)/2(r) $ and $\pi+ l(r)/2(r) $? It seems basic but I have spent a while trying to figure out its intuition.
NB: I have repeated the diagram here to make it easily accessible [image]

Comment: You should include the diagram in this question to make it self-contained. As it stands, we must click through to the other posts to understand your notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed value of $r$, the angle $\theta$ sweeps from point $A$ to point $B$. The length of the arc from $A$ to $B$ is $l(r)$. But arclength $s$ is just $r\theta$. So the angle swept out from $A$ to $B$ is $l(r)/r$. Half of this angle, $l(r)/(2r)$, is swept out from $A$ to the horizontal; the other half is swept from the horizontal to $B$.

To express the region in polar coordinates centered at the user circle, we measure $\theta$ relative to the horizontal. Point $A$ then corresponds to $\theta=\pi-l(r)/(2r)$, while point $B$ corresponds to $\theta=\pi+l(r)/(2r)$.

Comment: Quite clear and Brilliant! Thanks