# PDF of a distribution with a tuning parameter

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

I have been thinking about how to approach this problem for a while, and it still seems a little obscure to me. I will really appreciate a detailed answer with relevant Proof. I try to clearly describe it below:

---

Part A:

In Figure (a) (See below), $X$ is uniformly distributed in the smaller circle. I understand that the pdf is $f(x)= \dfrac{2 x}{r^2}$. Let's call this Case 1.

Now, let's say we modify this distribution, which we call "new distribution" with a "tuning factor," i.e for $0 \leq f < 2$, the pdf becomes

$$\frac{(2- f) r^{1-f}}{R^{2-f}}.$$

Note that with $f=0$ we have the same pdf as in Case 1.

---

Part B

In Figure (b), $X$ obeys a uniform distribution in the shaded region and $S$ is the area of the shaded region. $\ell(r)$ is the length of any arc $BPQ$. Points $A$ and $B$ are the centers of the intersecting circles with the same radii, respectively.

Distance between point $A$ to $X$ obeys $0 < r \leq R$.

I know the pdf of $r$, i.e. $f(r)$, is given by $\dfrac{\ell(r)}{S}$, which I clearly understand from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517888/probability-density-function-for-the-radius-half-the-length-of-two-equal-interse).

---

**My Question**:

How does the pdf $f(r)$ change with the new distribution in Part A? In other words, what is the new pdf given the shaded area in Figure (b) and its expectation?

[image]

Comment: Hint: if $X$ has the Case 1 pdf, $X^{1/(1-f/2)}$ has the more general pdf in Part A.

Comment: Please, although I voted this up it seems quite unclear to me

Comment: Please make only substantial edits. Bumping the question with pointless edits is noise.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Francisco.  $R$ is the mutual distance between A and B. The new distribution of $X$ in part 2 follows the modified distribution in part 1. So a general pdf which depend on $f$ based on this distribution is what I want to get.

Comment: @Abdulhameed I mean the new distribution of the point $X$, not the distance $r=|AX|$. The new distribution of $r$ is based on that of $X$, which is also omitted in part 1. If you just want the distribution of $r$ obeys some specific new distribution, then the configuration of circle $A$ and circle $B$ has nothing to do with ensuing calculation.

Comment: Yes @AlexFrancisco! The reason for including that detail is that the pdf of $r$ given by $\ell(r)/S$ depends on the area of the shaded region, $S$ i.e in the case for the uniform distribution.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco, that is for the one in Fig(a), the area of intersection of the circle will definitely reflect in the pdf as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517888/probability-density-function-for-the-radius-half-the-length-of-two-equal-interse). The main objective for the pdf  is to derive the expectation within the shaded area. Thanks for those clarifications. I have tried to redraw the diagrams also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}$Here is an answer based on one possible interpretation of the question. Denote the tuning factor by $c$ instead.

First, reverse-engineering from the modified density of $r$ in Case 1, the density of the point $X$ can be assumed as$$
f_1(x_1, x_2) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{2 - c}{2π R^{2 - c}} \dfrac{1}{(x_1^2 + x_2^2)^{\frac{c}{2}}}; & x_1^2 + x_2^2 < R^2\\
0; & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Now for Case 2, suppose the origin is $A$. Assume that $X$ has the above density conditioned to the shaded area $S$. Because in Case 1,$$
p := P(X \in S) = \iint\limits_{(x_1 - R)^2 + x_2^2 < R^2} f_1(x_1, x_2) \,\d x_1\d x_2,
$$
then the density of $X$ in Case 2 is$$
f_2(x_1, x_2) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{p} f_1(x_1, x_2); & (x_1 - R)^2 + x_2^2 < R^2\\
0; & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus the distribution of $r$ in Case 2 is\begin{align*}
&\peq F_r(r_0) = P(\|X\| \leqslant r_0)\\
&= \iint\limits_{x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leqslant r_0^2} f_2(x_1, x_2) \,\d x_1\d x_2 = \iint\limits_{\substack{r \leqslant r_0\\-π < θ \leqslant π}} f_2(r \cos θ, r \sin θ) r\,\d r\d θ\\
&= \int_0^{r_0} r\,\d r \int_{-π}^π f_2(r \cos θ, r \sin θ) \,\d θ = \int_0^{r_0} r\,\d r \int\limits_{r < 2R \cos θ} f_1(r \cos θ, r \sin θ) \,\d θ\\
&= \frac{1}{p} \int_0^{r_0} r\,\d r \int_{-\arccos \frac{r}{2R}}^{\arccos \frac{r}{2R}} f_1(r \cos θ, r \sin θ) \,\d θ = \frac{1}{p} \int_0^{r_0} r\,\d r \int_{-\arccos \frac{r}{2R}}^{\arccos \frac{r}{2R}} \frac{2 - c}{2π R^{2 - c}} \frac{1}{r^c} \,\d θ\\
&= \frac{1}{p} \int_0^{r_0} r · 2\arccos \frac{r}{2R} · \frac{2 - c}{2π R^{2 - c}} \frac{1}{r^c} \,\d r = \frac{2}{p} · \frac{2 - c}{2π R^{2 - c}} \int_0^{r_0} r^{1 - c} \arccos \frac{r}{2R} \,\d r,
\end{align*}
which implies the density is$$
f_r(r_0) = \frac{1}{p} · \frac{2 - c}{π R^{2 - c}} · r_0^{1 - c} \arccos \frac{r_0}{2R}. \quad \forall 0 < r_0 < R
$$

---

For the degenerate case $c = 0$, since by definition,$$
p = P(X \in S) = \iint\limits_{(x_1 - R)^2 + x_2^2 < R^2} f_1(x_1, x_2) \,\d x_1\d x_2 = \iint\limits_{(x_1 - R)^2 + x_2^2 < R^2} \frac{1}{πR^2} \,\d x_1\d x_2 = \frac{|S|}{πR^2},
$$
then$$
f_r(r_0) = \frac{1}{p} · \frac{2}{π R^2} · r_0 \arccos \frac{r_0}{2R} = \frac{2r_0}{|S|} \arccos \frac{r_0}{2R}.
$$

---

For $c = 0.5$,$$
f_r(r) = \frac{1}{p} · \frac{1.5}{π R^{1.5}} · \sqrt{r_0} \arccos \frac{r_0}{2R}. \quad \forall 0 < r_0 < R
$$
Here is a figure for $f_r$ and $F_r$:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks great! As a proof of correctness, please could you show that when $c=0$, $f(r) = \frac{2r_{0}\arccos(\frac{r_{0}}{2R})}{S}$ where $S= (\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt(3)}{2})R^2$? I have not been able to do this as I don't properly get the context of $p$

Comment: Also, @Alex, I wouldn't mind if you like to share the "reverse-engineering" process. Much thanks!

Comment: @Abdulhameed The “reverse-engineering” part is done like this: since$$\int_0^Rf(r)\,\mathrm dr=\int_0^R\int_{-π}^πf_X(r\cos θ,r\sin θ)r\,\mathrm dr\mathrm dθ,\tag{1}$$ in order to make $f_X$ not depend on $θ$, (1) becomes$$\int_0^Rf(r)\,\mathrm dr=2π\int_0^Rrf_X(r)\,\mathrm dr$$ and it suffices to take$$f_X(r\cos θ,r\sin θ)=f_X(r)=\frac{f(r)}{2πr}.$$

Comment: Yes! @Alex Francisco, you integrated over both $(x_1 - R)^{2} + x_2^2 < R^2$? That seems a little unclear to me. Then, if I have other values of $c$ where does it change (where do I manipulate) in the integral. Very much Thanks

Comment: @Abdulhameed This means the area of the double integration is that determined by this condition, i.e. the area is $\{(x_1,x_2)\in\mathbb R^2\mid(x_1-R)^2+x_2^2<R^2\}$. For different $c$, the integrand is different because $f_2$ has $c$ in its expression.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Please, at your convenience, for my benefit and others please show us an example with an arbitrary value of $c$ say $2$ or $3$ etc. Its a pleasure seeking clarifications from you. I am eligible to award the bounty in 6 hours time.

Comment: You answer is quite intuitive and well organized! Although, for $f_r$ you have shown. But peculiarly, steps on how we can get specific expressions given some $c$ (like you said). $E(r)$ would also be applauded! Many thanks

Comment: The application of this is that, $c$ determines how close the distribution of points would be within that area! That is why it would be very nice to see how to apply this using the expressions you have derived. Many thanks!

Comment: @Abdulhameed Well, the expression of $f_r$ is already given in the answer. Also, it seems that $E(r)$ has no closed form.

Comment: Thanks for the response. You haven't mentioned anything about the case where $c$ is other than $0$. Just to see how $(x_1^2 + x_2^2)^\frac{c}{2}$ fits into the picture. And that's all!

Comment: Please, what value did you use for $p$ ?

Comment: @Abdulhameed I didn't calculate $p$. The normalization is done by the graphing program.

Comment: Please I haven't been able to understand and follow your answer to this question line by line . If you don't mind could I request for the following: (1) The use of (${x_1}^2 + {x_2}^2) ^ {\frac{c}{2}}$ is not very clear to me, (2) The inclusion of $f_x(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)$ and the first two lines of the reverse engineering process.  Also, could you refer me to a reference material to understand this concept better. I will be so glad.

Comment: Thanks, you haven't mentioned anything about a suitable reference. Please if you don't mind could I request for the code for the graphs? Thanks