# Details on an interesting Proof on the modified PDF of two intersecting circles

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702758/pdf-of-a-distribution-with-a-tuning-parameter) brilliant answer has kept me busy for a while. The problem is that my mathematics is so basic that I will need a simpler step-by-step detail on how the transformations are done, then the parameter 'p'. Needless to say, a good mathematician should not find this a problem, but you know there are several perspectives towards detailing an answer.