# PDF Modification from a uniform to a way-point spatial distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Basically, I know that for a **uniformly distributed** points, r within the intersection $XQYD$ in Figure 1, the pdf is given by $$f(r) = \frac{l(r)}{A}$$ where A is the area of the intersection region and $l(r)$ is the length of $ACB$ and $\theta$ is given by $\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2R}\right)$ from Figure 2.

In case someone might find this useful

$$l(r) = 2r \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2R}\right) $$ while $$A = \left( \frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \right) $$

Question: Now suppose this changes to a non-uniform way-point spatial distribution. In this distribution, points are non-uniformly distributed around an arbitrary 'center' with a PDF

\begin{equation} f\left ({ r}\right )=\frac {1}{R^{2}}\left ({\frac {-4 \, r^{3}}{R^{2}}+4\, r}\right ) , \end{equation}

How do one go about modifying the PDF of $r$ i.e conditioning on the PDF above on the intersection of two equal circles?

In case it might be of interest, please note that to understand the pdf for the uniform distribution I have asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517888/probability-density-function-for-the-radius-half-the-length-of-two-equal-interse?noredirect=1&lq=1) before.

[image: figure]

Comment: I cannot make sense of your question. In the original setting you have a point which is uniformly distributed in a two dimensional region (this makes sense). Now you want to change from uniform to exponential or Weibull distribution. These are distributions of **one dimensional** random variables. So it does not make sense to say that a random point in a planar region has one of these distributions.

Comment: @GillesBonnet Thanks for that comment, the question has also been modified. I really appreciate that observation

Comment: OK. I think I understand what you are trying to do here. You can follow the same steps as in [the answer of Griboullis](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2517914/60457) in your previous question. You just need to plug in the integral the PDF of the random point, and change the normalizing constant $\frac{1}{S}$. This constant is just one over the integral computed with $r_0 = R$ because you want to have $\mathbb{P}(r\leq R) = 1$. This is the idea. The rest is computational. I leave this to you.